# How to manually animate iOS Large navigation bar titles?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ios11

I am using a sticky segmented control at the top of my view controller with a scrollable table view underneath it.

I am setting the navigation bar large title with

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

I would like to minimize the large title text to the navigation bar when the user scrolls. Unfortunately the text will not perform this default behavior because of the segmented control that sticks to the top when scrolling.

My first solution was to manually set the prefersLargeTitles = true/false based on scroll position. This will works however there is no animation which looks bad.

How can I achieve this effect? Is there a way to animate the text moving?

Comment: you can use `self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView` to set a `UILabel` for title and accordingly animate it.